# Can we remove "capability" from LWC xml file after it was added to Managed Package

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, lws

I want to implement [Dynamic component instantiation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-dynamic-components.html) to one of my **LWC** which is a part of **Managed Package**.

To do this a component's configuration file must include the `lightning__dynamicComponent` capability.
However it require **LWS**:

> To dynamically import and instantiate Lightning web components, you must [enable Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-enable.html).

The problem is that **not all** of our Customers have **LWS** **enabled**,
And if it is **disabled** a user will get next error:

[image]

So my **question** is:

- Can we remove `lightning__dynamicComponent` capability from the **LWC** after it was added to **Managed Package** and a new **major release version** was uploaded ?

--

From this doc: [Add Components to Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-packaging-add.html), it is **not clear** if we can edit it after release:

> After a package is released, the component name is locked, but the package developer can still edit these values in a component’s configuration file.
>
> - `apiVersion`
> - `description`
> - `isExposed` (can only change false to true)
> - `masterLabel`
> - `targetConfigs`
> - `targets`

If check [XML Configuration File Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-configuration-tags.html) doc, there are also nothing about it.

> A capability is something that a component can do, as opposed to a target, which defines where you can use a component.

*Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.*

Comment: All I can say is that I expect you will have problems because, despite what the documentation says, we found significant issues trying to update the target properties and configs in a packaged LWC.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks, I thought that there could be some problems . So I asked the question before making a release with a new "capability".

Comment: I look forward to reading an answer that confirms whether this is possible or not. Hoping, for you, it is. For our changes to targets and properties we actually had to deprecate the whole LWC and create a new one. Total PITA.